# Best Way to Set Day to the First of the Month Using DateTime Without Inherent WithDayOfMonth Method

Tags: java, date, datetime, jodatime, method-signature

So, I'm trying to basically take 2 DateTime objects and set them to the first day of their respective months so that I can ultimately calculate the months between the two dates.

Example of the code:

```
DateTime dt = new DateTime();
DateTime newDT = dt.withDayOfMonth(1);
```

And before anyone asks, the actual code coverts a Date object into a DateTime object which is used in another section of the code.

The issue is, when I do this in a unit test it seems to work just fine. However, when I try to test this using SOAP UI I can see in the course of debugging that I'm getting a runtime exception due to:

```
method lookup failed for selector "withDayOfMonth" with signature "(I)Lorg/joda/time/DateTime;"
```

In the corresponding server.txt log file, I can see a stack trace which indicates a **no such method** has occured.

After further research, I've found that our app server currently employs an outdated version of the JodaTime jar (1.2.1), while my eclipse library contains the correct jar (1.6.2).

However, now the question becomes what's the best way to accomplish my goal here (to create a new DateTime object with the first day of the month set to 0) since I don't have access to the withDayOfMonth method provided by JodaTime?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A possible way to do so, using another method for *Joda-Time* API which is present in *1.2.1* version it's the follow:

```
DateTime dateTime = new DateTime().dayOfMonth().withMinimumValue();
```

Another approach could be to use jdk `Calendar` to set the first day of the month for a date. And then get the joda `DateTime` using `DateTime(Calendar cal)` constructor:

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1); 
DateTime dateTime = new DateTime(cal);
```

However probably as other answer suggest the best you can do is update your *Joda-Time* version.

Comment: Both solutions work for my purposes. Thank you very much. Question, were you able to find the API documentation for 1.2.1 somewhere online? And as I said in my comment back to the previous answer, unfortunately upgrading our server is currently beyond my control and doesn't seem like it's going to happen any time soon.

Comment: @This0nePr0grammer I don't know if there are the old APIs for Joda-Time online, however from the follow link you can downloaded the src distribution zip which also contains the documentation inside the zip: https://sourceforge.net/projects/joda-time/files/joda-time/1.2.1/joda-time-1.2.1.zip/download

Answer (score 5):

## tl;dr

```
LocalDate firstOfThisMonth = 
    LocalDate.now( ZoneId.of( "America/Montreal" ) )
             .with( TemporalAdjusters.firstDayOfMonth() ) ;
```

## Details

Other answers address your Joda-Time question. However, the Joda-Time project is now in maintenance mode, with the team advising migration to the java.time classes. So here is a solution in java.time code.

### `LocalDate`

The [`LocalDate`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html) class represents a date-only value without time-of-day and without time zone.

A time zone is crucial in determining a date. For any given moment, the date varies around the globe by zone. For example, a few minutes after midnight in [Paris France](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Europe/Paris) is a new day while still “yesterday” in [Montréal Québec](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/America/Montreal).

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "America/Montreal" );
LocalDate today = LocalDate.now( z );
```

### `TemporalAdjuster`

The [`TemporalAdjuster`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/temporal/TemporalAdjuster.html) interface in java.time provides for classes to manipulate a value. The `TemporalAdjusters` class (note the plural `s`) provides several handy implementations of adjusters. One is [`firstDayOfMonth`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/temporal/TemporalAdjusters.html#firstDayOfMonth--).

```
LocalDate firstOfThisMonth = today.with( TemporalAdjusters.firstDayOfMonth() ) ;
```

> firstOfThisMonth.toString(): 2016-03-01

### `Period`

The `Period` class tracks a span of time not attached to the timeline. It keeps a number of years, months, and days.

```
LocalDate start = LocalDate.of ( 2016 , 1 , 1 ) ;
LocalDate stop = LocalDate.of ( 2016 , 3 , 1 ) ;
Period p = Period.between ( start , stop ) ;
```

Calling `toString` on a `Period` generates a string in standard [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Durations) format.

> P2M

You can ask for one part as a number, such as number of months.

```
int months = p.getMonths();
```

> 2

Note that the elapsed time shown here wisely uses the Half-Open approach where the beginning is *inclusive* while the ending is *exclusive*.

## About java.time

The [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`.Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`java.text.SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to java.time.

To learn more, see the [Oracle Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8) and [**SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9) and later

  - Built-in.
  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.
  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - The [*ThreeTenABP*](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts ***ThreeTen-Backport*** (mentioned above) for Android specifically.
  - See [*How to use…*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [ThreeTen-Extra](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).

Answer (score 2):

Calculate months from difference of the two month values. For example if `newDate` is 1st July 2016 and `oldDate` is 31st May 2016, `newDate.getMonth()` will return 7 and `oldDate.getMonth()` will return 5, and the difference will be rounded up as required.

```
int months = newDate.getMonth() - oldDate.getMonth();    // 7 - 5 = 2
```

Comment: Actually, given the requirement I do need it to over predict. And unfortunately, upgrading our weblogic server is beyond my control and it doesn't seem like there's any plan to do it in the near future.

Comment: In my opinion, it is a clean way to get the month values from the dateTime objects and subtract (Approach 2), rather than changing the date and setting it to 1.

Comment: If the requirement were different, I would agree with you, but in this instance I need it to essentially round up (which I believe you were saying this solution would not do).

Comment: I have edited my answer to show only the second approach, it will round up like you want.